# how to add conditional to blank select2 option? :include_blank => true?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ui-select2, select2-rails

When the select option is the blank placeholder, how can I find this, so I can execute the appropriate jquery / javascript?

here's my markup (haml) :

```
= form_tag(compare_path, method: 'get', remote: true, id: 'compare_form') do
          = select_tag "votus_friend_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@votus_friends, :id, :full_name, @comparison.votus_friend.id), :include_blank => true, :class => "compare-search", :style => "width:100%; margin-left: 3px;"
```

here's my JS. I know it's way off here. I can't seem to find the exact value that's coming back from select2 for the blank place holder in order to run the conditional:

```
$('.compare-search').on('change', function() {

  console.log('thisss', $('<select/>')  );

  if ($('.compare-search').val() === '') {
    $('.vScoreExplain').show();
    $('.stats').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('.vScoreExplain').hide();
    $('.stats').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.compare-search').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).val().length) {
    $('.vScoreExplain').hide();
    $('.stats').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.vScoreExplain').show();
    $('.stats').hide();
  }
});
```